# Detecting PII and redacting using Video Indexer and Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

I am trying to create a custom transform to detect and replace Pii information in videos using video indexer and media services, but I am not able to find the correct workflow to use the services? video indexer detects insights (OCR)-> text analytics detects Pii -> Media Services encodes and blurs (or overlay) the regions in video? There is no sample for media services to blur regions only faceredaction

Comment: as far as I know, there's no such function available on Azure Media Services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Services API only supports the detection of faces and the blurring of them in a two-pass or single-pass process.

The two-pass process returns a JSON file with bounding boxes that can be used to adjust the positioning and choose which areas are blurred or not blurred.  That file can be updated and then used in the second pass.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/analyze-face-redaction-concept

also see the JSON schema here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/analyze-face-redaction-concept#elements-of-the-output-json-file

The current .NET sample for this only shows the single-pass mode being used though, and I don't yet have a detailed sample showing the process of editing and re-submitting the job for the second pass, but I can help with that if you are interested in the details.
The current sample uses the "Redact" mode, but you would want to start with the "Analyze" mode if you merely wanted the JSON file with the bounding boxes to be used for blurring adjustments.

There is no support to blur text or OCR related data directly in the service or in Video Indexer.

Comment: how can I create my own redactor?

Comment: Not supported with AMS, but you could write something custom with gStreamer and a framework for video AI like OpenVino from Intel or the Nvidia Deepstream SDKs